# How to show the user the default windows authentication prompt from a windows form using c#?

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

I thought this would be a very common practice, but I am having a hard time finding anything on how to show the user a default windows authentication credential prompt in c#?

Users will be using this windows forms app to connect to a web service on a different domain, so I cant just pass in the default credentials. These users will have a separate login to access the web service, and I want them to be prompted by the default Windows prompt, and then I can pass their creds through to the web service.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was answered on SO a while back, I believe. You can use the credential management API. Here's a [link](http://www.developerfusion.com/code/4693/using-the-credential-management-api/) with a  code example that should get you started.

Answer (score 2):

You need to P/invoke [`CredUIPromptForWindowsCredentials`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa375178%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) on Vista and up, or [`CredUIPromptForCredentials`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa375177%28VS.85%29.aspx) on XP.

Comment: Thank you very much, can you please provide an example using this? Also, I do not want to authenticate the user / talk to AD at all here. I just want to ask the user for their creds, and use them to make a call to the web service.

Comment: Start with the code in the link that Patrick has given you. You should accept his answer. It's the best on offer.